# Two WP Issues: Redirect Loop and Can't Login

Tags: wordpress

Recently uploaded my site from localhost to the live server, and it's not quite working. When I visit the home page, the browser says Im stuck in a redirect loop. I've tried the default fixes like resetting .htaccess file, disabling all plugins, switching to default theme, and clearing cookies, and none of these worked.

Second issue (maybe related?) is when I try to login via wp-admin and hit Login, it basically just refreshes the page and nothing happens. Definitely using the right credentials.

I was using the Understrap theme if that matters, with some of my own plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the same database of your local Installation on the live Server? Maybe some worng paths in **options** table could be wrong causing your problems, if you migrated your local database to the live server. Maybe you also need to check **wp-config.php** and set your base url here or sth.

Comment: base url's are all set. I did import the same database but I updated the URL paths in the sql file. I'm seeing now via Redirect Checker that the 301 redirects are alternating between www and not www.